# Ants AI Challenge: How can I write to a file from within my Ant class?

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence

For a final project in my AI class, I'm working on the Google AI Ants challenge (from 2011). I'm using a diffusion based approach, and I want to be able to visualize the diffusion field (which is a numpy array) for debugging/presentation purposes.

Normally I'd do something like `numpy.save("myFile",array)`, but the main file that runs all of the Ants stuff seems to redirect I/O. For example, if I want my bot to print to terminal, I can't just do `print "Hello World"`, I have to do `sys.stderr.write("Hello World")`.

I know this isn't that helpful, and I'm not sure which code to paste, so I'm really hoping someone who had experience with the challenge can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the specifics to the Google AI Ants challenge, but could you just use standard Python file operations?

```
with open("myFile", "w") as f:
    # print each element on a separate line
    for elem in array:
        f.write(repr(elem))
```

This would require you to define how the array is written to and read from the file, just as `numpy.save()` would do.
--ap

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work with the `with open` statement.

`numpy.save` takes a string or a file, and I was originally using a string but it wasn't working for some reason (because of the I/O redirecting maybe?). Now that I'm calling with a file it seems to be working correctly.

I'm pretty weak with system stuff, so thanks again, I really appreciate it.